# How to set up the relationships in Rails for multiple Collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A user has many games. A game have many squares.   Now each square has a user_id but im NOT checking to see if that user has any squares but rather can that user change details about that square (does it belong to a game the user has access to).  Now I want to do something like this to check for permissions.

```
Select * from squares 
left join games on squares.game_id = games.id
left join users on games.user_id = users.id
where squares.id =

@user.games.squares.find(1)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games  

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :squares  

class Square < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
```

Comment: how is that user has many games, but game doesn't have belongs_to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this `@user.squares.find(1)` by changing

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games 
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :squares
end
```

to this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games 
  has_many :squares through: :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :squares
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: he could do `@user.games.squares.find(1)` without has_many :through, didn't he? The point is straight `@user.squares.where(:game_id=>@user.games)`

Comment: When I try @user.games.squares I get undefined method `squares' for #<Game::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbea44c8988>

Comment: Oh sorry I meant ```@user.squares``` updating my answer

Comment: @JoeHalfFace What you said does give me the query I am looking for! Not sure if there is a way to do that with relationships in each model

Comment: @JohnPollard, sorry I quite didn't get what did you mean by 'if there is a way to do that with relationships in each model'

Comment: @JoeHalfFace its starting to make sense now thank you